# Google me rechaza mi actualización por un error al declarar un permiso sensible y no sé como quitarlo del formulario

Tags: android, android-permissions, appinventor

en primer lugar gracias por leer mi problema. No soy programador profesional pero conseguí hacer una app com appinventor y colgarla con éxito en Google Store que, entre sus funciones, se podian hacer llamadas directas. Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema ha venido al querer añadir notificaciones push con One Signal. Como appinventor no tiene esa extension migré el proyecto a kodular sin ningún problema aparente.

Al colgar la actualización google me advirtió que havia permisos sensibles añadidos en la versión que ponia. Uno de ellos el ONGOING_CALL. Al ver que Kodular havia hecho algun tipo de modificacion opté por quitar del manifiesto ese permiso pero luego me daba un error 908.

Al ver que no sabia solucionarlo y con el ansia de provar la actualización inicié el Formulario de declaración de permisos pensadno que más adelante lo podria solucionar quitando de nuevo la petición. Mi sorpresa fué que me deniegan cada actualización incluso quitando,no solo el permiso en el manifiesto, sino que quité las llamadas directas. El problema se que viene de haber declarado ese permiso en el formulario pero no puedo quitar ese permiso del apartado del formulario de declaración de permisos. Ya no sé que provar, envio peticiones a google pero solo me han contestado una vez diciendo que pruebe a mirar las ayudas de google play console.

Agradeceré cualquier ayuda que puedan proporcionarme.

Por si les sirve de ayuda pongo el apartado que me gustaria "resetear":

***Declarar permisos sensibles
If your app requests to use sensitive permissions, such as SMS or Call Log permission groups, you must complete the Permissions declaration form.
Your app may be suspended from Google Play if you don't report functionality which uses these permissions. Más información
check_circle_outline
1 permiso declarado anteriormente
android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS***

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. No sé prograrmar en código. Me da verguenza admitirlo. Solo programo en bloque con appinventor y kodular. Podria poner el manifiesto y alguna otra configuracion ya que uso Apk Editor Studio para fimar y empaquetar los últimos pasos de los APK. Aunque creo que he identificado el problema. En el formulario de google play console puse la opción: automatización de dispositivo y me he dado cuenta que quizás deberia haber puesto: Controlador predeterminado de teléfono que es lo que he enviado ahora esperando que contesten. Quizas puedas confirmarme si estoy en lo cierto

Comment: Agrega el manifest porque en ese archivo hay que agregar el permiso.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar [ask], modifica tu pregunta por favor, saludos.

Comment: ¡Resuelto! Como me temia en la publicación anterior la solución era poner en el formulario de permisos sensibles de Google Play Store: Controlador predeterminado de teléfono. Muchas gracias Bicho y Jorgersys por su tiempo y perdonen las molestias, estoy muy agradecido y recomendaré este sitio a mis colegas. Un saludo!!

Comment: La solución va en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta, por favor lee [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto! Como me temia en la publicación anterior la solución era poner en el formulario de permisos sensibles de Google Play Store: Controlador predeterminado de teléfono.